# How to modify file's date programmaticaly?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, date

I have some image files with the wrong date (date of file creation, the value that is shown by `ls -l`), because it was set wrong in the camera. How can I increment the date by two days in a script changing all *.jpg files in a directory? Bash, Perl, what ever runs on a Linux machine and is appropriate for the job would be fine.

Searching the web I found that `touch` is used to manipulate date, but I did not found a way incrementing it by two days, while preserving the time.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give example of a file name/contents showing where date is encoded. And show what you tried please.

Comment: Edited question in order to give some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch` is the tool for the job.

```
for file in P123*.JPG ; do
    touch --date="$(date -r $file) + 2 days" $file
done
```

Comment: I had to modify your solution to make it working, but finally i managed to do so. The working solution was: ``for file in *.JPG; do touch -d "`date -r $file '+%F %T'` 2 days" $file; done`` Your solution always gave error: "invalid date", thats why I added the formatting option `+%F %T` and the `+` gave completely weird results (`+ 2 days` added one day, and `+ 3 days` added one day minus 1 hour).

Comment: @Twonky: Do you have non-English `locale` in effect?

Answer (score 5):

I guess that instead of modifying the date of the file (like all other responses @this time), you would like to modify the *metadatas*, so see this page : http://savvyadmin.com/fixing-dates-in-image-exif-tag-data-from-linux/

you have to use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) (or exiv2) like this :

```
jhead -ts2003:01:01-00:00:00 image.jpg
```

---

Last but not least, there's a special switch `-ta` to modify directly the date : ex. for 2 days later :

```
for i in *.jpg; do jhead -ta+48:00 "$i"; done
```

Comment: See my edited post with a loop to add 2 days to each JPG files in one line

Comment: +1: Yes, it's the META Data that must be modified, and not the file date itself.

Comment: No I really meant the file date. However changing the metadata date would be the next step. I didn't think of that so far, so thanks for the hint. I guess it depends on how you organize your fotografs whether file date or the date in the metadata is important.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) to change modtime.

Use [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) to operate on the date.

Untested:

```
for f in *jpg; do
  mtime=`date -r $f`
  nextt=`date "$mtime + 2 days"`
  touch -d "$nextt" $f
done
```

Comment: The documentation for touch behind your link suggests that you either need the -t or -d option to make this work